# Indexing and Retrieving XML Data using Lucene

Tags: xml, xslt, lucene

I have 10 million articles in XML format. A sample structure is given below-

```
<address-book>
  <contact type="individual">
   <name c="10">Zane Pasolini</name>
   <address>999 W. Prince St.</address>
   <city>New York</city>
   <province>NY</province>
   <postalcode>10013</postalcode>
   <country>USA</country>
   <telephone>1-212-345-6789</telephone>
  </contact>
  <contact type="business">
   <name c="11">SAMOFIX d.o.o.</name>
   <address>Ilica 47-2</address>
   <city>Zagreb</city>
   <province/>
   <postalcode>10000</postalcode>
   <country>Croatia</country>
   <telephone>385-1-123-4567</telephone>
  </contact>
</address-book>
```

I am using Lucene 4.x for indexing these XML Files. I also have a XSLT to
transform these XML files, so that the user can view them in well decorated format.

I want to know that after indexing, will the XML strucure be intact or loose
the format ? For Ex- if the user searches "individual" contact type, then can I
retrieve all the data inclduing XML nodes, so that my XSLT will transform them into 
well decorated HTML?

Comment: The answer here depends entirely on your implementation.  A fairly typical implementation is to keep the XML documents intact and retrieve the original after it is received as a search result from Lucene.  The [Lucene documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/) has some good resources for getting started, as does [the wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/FrontPage?action=show&redirect=FrontPageEN)

Comment: @femtoRgon - Can you put more light on this? I mean how can this be done?

Comment: I am also looking for the same.

Comment: Index content, and retrieve them from disk when found.  Or store all the content in the index if you prefer.  Either would work.  The demo application Lucene provides all but implements this for you.  Do you have some particular problem you are running into?